# Excel: Can you limit the output of the LARGE function to a number of rows where duplicate values are present?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have Excel data like the below table. My table has duplicate values in COL B but they are attached to unique values in COL A. I want to find the top 5 values and cut-off after 5 rows.Can this be done?

My existing formula is:

=SORT(FILTER(A1:B7,B1:B7>=LARGE(A1:B7,5),2,-1))

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Name A | 56 |
| Name B | 20 |
| Name C | 30 |
| Name D | 20 |
| Name E | 45 |
| Name F | 38 |
| Name G | 20 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in INDEX and use two SEQUENCE to only return the top 5 and the 2 columns:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A1:B7,B1:B7>=LARGE(A1:B7,5)),2,-1),SEQUENCE(5),SEQUENCE(,2))
```

[image]